# Minimal parameter change causes dramatic different behaviour & "no root found" warning - Open Modelica

Tags: parameters, warnings, modelica, openmodelica

I encountered an issue in my 1D mechanical model in OpenModelica, where a very small change in a coulomb friction parameter value below a certain treshold causes dramatically different behavior, and i get a "Warning: maximal number of iteration reached but no root found" in that case. Both seem to be connected.

Specifically in this case, the parameter is a static friction torque that leads to (what seem to be) plausible results for values of >=0.097524Nm   vs.  <=0.097523, which lead to strong oscillations and the "no root" warning (see images below)

**Question:** How i can try and solve this type of issue in general in OpenModelica? What kind of tools/logs can i look to aid finding the cause? 
I don't know at which point the warning occurs, but i have a suspicion - is there a way to check in detail?

*The model is a bit too complex to post here (imo), as it simulates pulling of flexible rope/foil through several buffer elements -> 975 equations, including many custom components (mainly friction/contact elements using continually differentiable equations/ sigmoid functions rather than if-conditions) - i would like to try and look for the issue myself first, but i don't know exactly where to start*

Example of the nature of the different reaction (Red is motor torque, green is velocity of rope)

"Plausible result" for >=0.097524 Nm friction torque
[image: plausible result for 0.097524 Nm friction torque]

"implausible result" for <=0.097523 Nm friction torque
[image]

Now, the treshold values dont appear to be exact values - if i change other parameters it will slightly change the behaviour. For another parameter set for example i get this behaviour (and 6x no root warning, whereas before it was only 1 warning)
[image]

Comment: In OpenModelica you may click on `Debug more`, which should be an available option under the Warning. Here you can look up the exact equation which leads to the error. Maybe you can go backwards from the equation and re-write the original equation for it to be more stable. If this does not help, try a minimal example in which the error also occurs. You may post the minimal example here, so we can also have a guess on the problem.